# cann't add mysql db table in vb datasource

Tags: mysql, vb.net

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CeFr.png)I installed mysql 8.0.3 in windows 10 with visual studio 2017. I created DB and table in mysql but when I want to add it through VB Windows form App in data source I got this error

```
Could not retrieve schema information for table or view `testtable`.
```

I can added it from server explorer tab and test connection is OK.

What I have to do to solve this issue?

Thanks for all

[Server Explorer in Visual studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAcEO.png)

[Adding dataset-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c1o1.png)

[Adding dataset-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c1o1.png)

[Adding dataset-3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOTJo.png)

[error-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdMW6.png)

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8dzj.png)

[mysql config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXGBt.png)

Comment: Any Idea guys :)

Comment: Most likely, you will need to grant access to MySQL's information_schema database, like: grant select on information_schema.* to <your user>

Comment: @Christos I made a grants for my testdb schema in the root privilege but still has the same error!

Comment: I noticed something which the table is granted but the column privileges not granted, how to grant the column inside table?

Comment: @Christos now the table db and column are granted with root user but still get the same error?

Comment: Are you connecting with the same user from visual studio, also does the table has any schema? (Columns)

Comment: @Christos yes I am using the root user from visual studio  and the table has two columns but I cann't see them in dataset and I can see full table with column in server explorer tab.

Comment: @Christos I added screenshots to be more clear

Comment: Any Idea upon the screenshots

Comment: I installed the windows 10 again and reinstalled visual studio and mysql 8.0 but still has the same error!

Comment: I noticed this issue and I don't know why?

First time I opened the VS 2015 and connect to Database :localhost/root in server explorer tab it's OK and when I right click on table to retrieve data from table is OK and retrieved with Columns data in the table, But when create new project with VB.NET windows form App and try to add dataset I got "Could not retrieve schema information for table or view"

and when I go back to server explorer to retrieve the data didn't work until I closed the VS and reopen it again!

What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved!

The whole problem is from connector. but not only uninstalled and reinstalled will solve the issue.

What I did is go to

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies
```

and delete MySql.Data.dll file then installed mysql-connector-net-6.9.8 for mysql 5.7

this is what finally solved my problem with deeply troubleshooting.

Thanks for all here