# Can Add table Database in server explorer but not in data source

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, mysql-workbench

I am using VS 2015 and MySQL 5.7 with connector 6.9.9 and I created a table database and can retrieve the data from Visual Studio in server explorer tabe but when i need to add it in data source for VB.NET window App form I got error

```
  "Could not retrieve schema information for table or view "
```

I don't know where is the problem here...I reinstalled my OS and VS and MySQL but no hope! What is the best stable SDK because also I tried most of SDK but not working!

Also I granted the table in myswl workbench and checked from cli is granted!

Comment: Please explain EXACTLY what you did when that error was generated.  You need to be VERY specific when posting questions in places like this because we only know what you tell us so you ned to tell us everything that is relevant.  If it doesn't work then, most likely, you did something wrong so we need to know what you actually did. If we have to guess then we're likely to guess wrong.

Comment: @jmcilhinney thanks for reply, I am still in the first step when I created a database table with column in mysql 5.7 and made granted for table in root user. then I went to visual studio (VB.NET windows app form) to add dataset but when I added the table database the column didn't retrieve it with table.

Comment: the solution is in this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224812/cannt-add-mysql-db-table-in-vb-datasource/53297303#53297303